# Combine: Publisher like Future but with multiple values

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I have 3d party library (`Firestore`) that has this method

```
func listenToEvents(handler: ([Result], Error) -> Void)
```

`handler` in this method is called many times (after any updates of the data). I want to convert it to `Publisher`

Here is my code now:

```
var resultsPublisher: AnyPublisher<[Result], Error> {
    Deferred { 
        Future { promise in
           libraryObject.listenToEvents { results, error in // called multiple times
              guard let results = results else {
                 promise(.failure(error))
                 return
              }

              // this can't be called several times,
              // because Future's promise is supposed to be called only once
              promise(.success(results))
           }
         }
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

So my `Publisher` produces value only once, because `Future` works this way. Are there any other `Publishers` (or may be a different approach) to accomplish that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is possible alternate approach. No needs in `Defer`, 'cause subject lives idle, and can send (pass-through) as many values as `libraryObject` will live.

Tested with Xcode 11.4.

```
var resultsPublisher: AnyPublisher<[Result], Error> {
    let subject = PassthroughSubject<[Result], Error>()
    libraryObject.listenToEvents { results, error in // called multiple times
        guard let results = results else {
            subject.send(completion: .failure(error))
            return
        }

        subject.send(results)
    }
    return subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```